# Creating YouTube videos in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, video, iphone-sdk-3.0, youtube-api

I'm doing a project where we want to create a video inside an iPhone app and upload it to YouTube. I've seen the you upload the video using Google's Data API (http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/).

However it seems that you need to upload the movie as an actual movie. Has anyone got any experience on making a movie in a format that YouTube will accept via the Data API and care to give me a few pointers on what would work?

(Just a quick note, I cannot use hidden APIs for this project)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube accepts a broad range of formats. Just try it yourself, use any free video editing software to create a short movie and upload that movie to youtube, you're almost guaranteed that youtube would be able to process that.
The second part of your question is whether ios is able to produce a movie from still frames, then the answer is - yes - and you want to look at [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188), particularly at [AVAssetWriter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAssetWriter)